# Google Address GeoCoding ROOFTOP accuracy degraded?

Tags: google-geocoder

Has anyone else noticed that the accuracy of the lat/long returned as ROOFTOP is now quite a bit off on the ground from what it was in the past?

I used to get lat/longs truly on rooftops, now the points are in the street in front of the address if I'm lucky, or one to two addresses away. I was depending on the accuracy to be good enough to pick the parcel for an address - now the pin in the right of way or one/two parcels away. I guess this is better for driving but they can no longer call the accuracy ROOFTOP.

I'm using free access (very low volume) - has Google degraded the accuracy on purpose? Can we pay a to get the accuracy back?

Is there another free/cheap resource out there for true rooftop points?

Comment: I switched to Yahoo! Their API provides a choice of routing or display points.

Comment: Yahoo! appears to have the same issues, I was wrong about the display points - that is part of the Bing geocoder.